# Proper AspectRation and PlotRange options with Graphics[]

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization, algebra, interactive

I have code:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Line[{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}], Axes->True, AspectRatio->Automatic, PlotRange->{-10, 10}],{x1,-1,10,Appearance->"Labeled"},{y1,-1,10,Appearance->"Labeled"},{x2,-1,10,Appearance->"Labeled"}, {y2,-1,10,Appearance->"Labeled"}]
```

This code manipulates lines `x1`, `y1`, `x2` ,`y2` points. It draws line properly and manipulates. The problem is with `AspectRatio->Automatic, PlotRange->{-10, 10}` they do not work. Scale of `x` axis is not same as for `y` axis while I am manipulating values. The x axis is moving while I am manipulating values. If I remove `AspectRatio->Automatic, PlotRange->{-10, 10}` or `PlotRange->{-10, 10}` scale of x and y axises are becoming the same but the border of the plot changes when moving sliders.

**Question:** How to make `AspectRatio->Automatic, PlotRange->{-10, 10}` behave as it works for `Plot[]`, so that scale of the axeses should be same and the plot size should not change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you.

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[Line[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}], Axes -> True, 
            PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], 
            {x1, -1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
            {y1, -1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
            {x2, -1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
            {y2, -1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```